# Why is "Adjust for TV" missing in ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: 20.04, graphics

How do I give computer hardware info?

Why is "Adjust for TV" missing in ubuntu 20.04.4 on an up-to-date Toshiba laptop?

A 20.04 installation USB stick has the switch and it works on my desktop.

Comment: Is your Toshiba notebook connected to an external monitor? If not, then "Adjust for TV" would make no sense to present, as there's no need to overscan on a built-in LCD panel 

Comment: The Toshiba notebook IS connected to the COBY 32 TV. The laptop uses the COBY as an extension on a second HDMI input.